# Window.onload vs procedural execution

Tags: javascript, onload

When using procedural style the code seemed to be executing with the wrong width dimensions of an element (i suspect the code was executing before the element was finished being created), when i refreshed the page all was fine.

Issue:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="parent">
        </div>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            create_object(); // Creates an element and puts it inside div parent
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
                create_object(); // Creates an element and puts it inside div parent
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="parent">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the difference?
The window.onload waits for the page to load of course but since the  is after the element.. shouldn't that be just fine?

No other java script is being executed on the page.

Comment: I really want to stay away from using the window onload event with this, but isn't absolutely necessary.

Comment: by the way the sizing isnt completely off its off by like 10 pixels or so. (maybe its margin or padding or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.onload` waits for all page resources (such as images and style sheets) to be loaded before calling its callback.  In your first example, the DOM elements will all exist (because your code is executing at the end of the body after things before it have been parsed), but external resources like images may not yet be loaded and thus final layout may not yet be achieved so everything may not yet have its final size/layout.

Comment: I was hoping someone would give this as an answer, do fonts count as a resource? That could be the issue maybe? because i am using my own font type

Comment: @RichardGrant - I was not able to find a definitive answer on whether `window.onload` always waits for font resources to load, but it does appear to wait in at least some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

window.onload is executed when DOM tree is ready and all resources are loaded (image, script, stylesheet ...). If you load your script in body without this callback, your div width can be wrong if you load image or stylesheet into this bloc ...